# Stuck at a top company that discriminates arbitrarily

Tags: salary, job-offer, job-change, discrimination

I work for a big corporation that is one of the best in the business. I joined with a bunch of many other fresh graduates, at an offshore location. After joining, I found out that the firm had hired people arbitrarily - some were given a higher position and salary than others, for the same exact work, for no reason other than they could. I felt discriminated against and I was assured that remediation steps would be taken, which did not happen.

My ratings are high but it's been a couple of years and the appraisals have been terrible - barely covering inflation, not to mention that I am still stuck at a lower grade than my colleagues. The firm is also hiring new graduates which are my seniors by default because they're hired at a higher position.

However, the company's work culture, skill level of my colleagues is arguably the best in the business, and although I enjoy work, I feel that I am treated by arrogance by the highest management - my work is not valued, and they have not promoted me in 2.5 years.

This has affected my morale terribly, I derive a large part of my work satisfaction at the very least on NOT being systematically discriminated against. The company seems to be cognizant yet dismissive of their errors.

I recently got a much better offer from a firm that is also of great quality, but not as good as this one. Upon discussing with my manager, he stressed I should look at long term oppurtunities being part of a great team (the team is indeed great- people are smart and many stay on for a long long time so they're likely being taken care of), he also said I will be happy this appraisal cycle so I should wait for it - however I have no faith in the management; not to mention that their hiring incompetence is well known. I am also sure there is no way they can match the offer I have - my manager has also indicated that they will not enter into a negotiation.

Generally speaking, is it worth it to stay in a great team and culture with only the dangling of long term growth keeping you there?

Comment: “Should I…” is not a good question for this site. However the other offer is from a company “also of great quality but not as good as this one.” Yet you have described “this one” as treating you poorly and doing precisely the opposite of what gives you satisfaction. Consider your manager’s comment to look long term as manipulation, and assume the promise that you will be happy this cycle as empty. Then you will know what to do.

Comment: I understand. I've changed the question a bit. Well the overall current firm reputation is much better, its performance is stronger, but in my context I've been treated like dogshit by local management. May I please ask why you think the manager's comments are not genuine?

Comment: "However, the company's work culture, skill level of my colleagues is arguably the best in the business" this sounds like either you rationalising or them selling you on the company. Or both.

Comment: Its got nothing to do with either, it is an objective view of almost all the people working in my domain - peers, friends, colleagues.

Comment: "big corporation that is one of the best in the business" -- well, based on your description I wouldn't call them that at all.

Comment: being treated badly is not the same thing as discrimination.

Comment: I think the comments are not genuine because if they valued you then they would have given you a raise last time.  You yourself literally wrote “I have no faith in the management.” Disclaimer: I don’t know any of these people so I have no idea if they are genuine. If you want to stay then stay.

Comment: Words are free, ignore literally everything management tells you is coming in the future. It's almost impossible to get a significant raise without a job title change or threatening to leave and getting yourself on the list of people with a foot out the door. So to answer... Is it worth it if you only got the team and nothing else? Because mgmts words are as valuable as the air spoken with. You ask when that's happening 9 months down the road and they'll just restructure your team and you'll have a diff. Mgr saying oh, wait a few more months it's coming   I'll ask 

Comment: You wasted time "discussing with manager". Give yourself a good talking to, and decide for yourself. Is there any answer or comment here that says "Great, the manager told you the truth, wait it out"?

Comment: @TigerGuy People with the same education as me, and no work experience, are hired on a higher salary and position than me. How is that not discrimination?

Comment: from the google definition:  "the unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people or things, especially on the grounds of race, age, or sex."  Everyone at work is treated differently because people are different.  Discrimination means being treated badly based on a non-work attribute.

Comment: Ok so what is the work attribute that caused them to differentiate me before handing me the offer letter?

Comment: How should we know?  Sometimes life isn't fair, sometimes it is.   Your education, grades, interview ability?

Comment: That's kind of absurd considering they made me an offer before they did it to anyone else, even before people had their second round interviews. I answered all the interview questions, the interviewer was thoroughly impressed. My grades were good enough that they asked me repeatedly if I was considering a PhD.  Not to mention the management has no response when I have asked the the reason. Perhaps there is something you know that the management doesn't @TigerGuy

Comment: If you don't feel valued, don't have faith in management, you know they have a piss-poor talent management, how exactly do you see a prospect for long-term growth there?

Answer (score 8):

> Generally speaking, is it worth it to stay in a great team and culture
> with only the dangling of long term growth keeping you there?

What has history shown you? You've not been promoted in 2.5 years. You're underpaid in comparison to your peers. New employees are being hired at levels above you. Does that support the statements your manager made about the next cycle? From my perspective, the historic evidence doesn't support those statements.

Can you pay your bills with a great team and culture? Will a great team and culture help you achieve your financial goals? At the end of the day, we work because we need to work in order to earn a living to pay for things. Rent, mortgage, utilities, groceries, vacations, etc., etc. You can't pay for any of those teams with a great team and culture.

Is it worth it to stay? Not for me it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

This is, of course, a very personal question.

Leaving a job is scary, especially the first few times you do it. But I think that most people in tech would agree that they have to move jobs regularly to maximize their compensation (since major upward bumps only happen upon entry to a new position).

You have a track record of promises not being kept at the current company, so their credibility value is close to null.

Furthermore, if they really were on the cusp of paying you more they could/should do it **right now**, since you already put them on notice of leaving. Even then, many people would say you shouldn't accept such a counteroffer (me, I'd think that on the order of double the new company's increase would be proper for the time and energy you've lost). But you're not even getting *that*.

Given how personal this is, one tenet of mine is: Trust your gut. How does your gut feel when you try on the idea of staying vs. leaving?

A second tenet is: About 2 years is enough to get the educational value out of any particular workplace.

So in response to the current question:

> Generally speaking, is it worth it to stay in a great team and culture
> with only the dangling of long term growth keeping you there?

I would opine no.

Comment: As someone who has faced discrimination and being singled out from a young age every now and then, it is indeed an emotional issue for me - I've lied awake many times at night thinking of the lack of dignity at work. Safe to say my gut certainly leans towards taking the new job. On the other hand, certainly the potential in my current team is hard to match.

Comment: @user121416: Well, your question didn't give any evidence of the company's "potential" being connected to any benefits to _you_.

Comment: @user121416 - Everything you described indicated are about your colleagues, like your colleagues being the best in the business, and you indicated your company is able to attract that talent by paying them what the are worth.  What you don’t describe is how, you are among “the best in the business”, honestly it doesn’t sound like your faced with discrimination specifically. It sounds like you have simply lost faith in yourself. You questioned the reason you have not received a raise, but you only talk about the skills of your colleagues instead of yourself

Comment: I am new to employment, I am not the best in any way yet. Sue, for my experience and age, there is no question that I have a great reputation. People in different teams come and ask me questions, and I have conducted training for 30 people who were hired at a more senior position than me. My rating for the first year was the highest among the whole bunch of fresh hires, even those at a more senior level.

Comment: @Donald by 'certainly the potential in my current team is hard to match', I meant it is hard to match by other firms. I have no reason to doubt my capability whatsoever, I feel valued by my colleagues from a skill persepective.

Comment: @user121416 - Are you sure that your inability to get a raise doesn’t have something to do with the fact you just started at the company, and apparently have little experience, if you are new to employment?

Comment: @Donald the standard timeline for promotion is 2 years for anyone who starts. I've 2.5 years of experience now. And anyways, I'm only asking for what others were given out for free, but even that cannot happen at this place.

Answer (score 1):

Manager would say anything to keep you at your place.

By the time year end rolls in and your raise is nothing, would be too late to switch.

Best raises I got in my carrier were due to job switch and not internal remunerations

Comment: Do many companies even give raises internally anymore? I was under the impression that this was mostly not a thing unless you work for the government or an org with a forced pay scale. I always assumed to get a raise you just switch jobs.

Comment: @ribs2spare its usually called cost of living raise 1-3%